# Проблемы с установкой Apache

Tags: apache, windows

Здравствуйте!

Устанавливаю на ПК с WinXP `httpd-2.2.22-win32-x86-no_ssl.msi`. Перед завершением установки появляется черного цвета окно с сообщением:

> `C:\Server\Apache\bin\httpd.exe`
>
> `Installing the Apache2.2 serviceThe Apache2.2 servise is successfully installed.httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified name, using 93.180.241.40 for ServerName (OS 10048) здесь какой-то набор русских букв : make_sock: could not address 0.0.0.0:80 no listening sokets avaliable, shutting downUnable to open logsNote the errors or messeges above, and press the <ESC> key to exit.`

А потом стандартное об успешном завершении установки:

> `The instaliation has sccessfully finished.`

Windows автоматически запускает апач, но вместо зеленого треугольника в трее - красный квадратик. Когда пытаюсь запустить (Start) выдает сообщение об ошибке:

> `The request operation has failed!`

Не знаю, что делать дальше. Кто-нибудь может помочь?

Answer (score 1):

1. Проверьте нету-ли чего уже запущенного на 80м порту (Скайп, например).
2. Посмотрите в конфигурации, файл `httpd.conf`, директиву `ServerName`, если там стоит что-то отличное от вашего IP или имени вашего компьютера, то сами пропишите ваше DNS имя, если вы его не имеете достаточно указать IP. Формат `IP:Port` или `Host:Port`, например

---

```
ServerName www.example.com:80ServerName 76.12.1.2:80
```

Comment: Чтобы узнать, что там висит на 80-том порту можно воспользоваться [tcpview][1]  [1]: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437

Comment: Да есть же стандартное решение. `netstat -n -b -s -p TCP` и искать в локальных адресах то, что с портом 80

Answer (score 0):

Можно погрешить на то что httpd.conf и в нем какая-то ошибка закралась.

Может там грузятся библиотеки, которых и в помине нет, так что скорее всего там проблемы.